# Eclipse Debug , change variable value on BigDecimal

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, bigdecimal

How can I provide a `BigDecimal` value while debugging in Eclipse in Variables section?

Eg:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(21);
if(bd.equals(new BigDecimal(20))) {
..
}
```

I have set the break point on the `if` statement, now I want to change the `bd` value to `20`, so that my `if` block executes while debugging. I have tried it many ways, but I am getting an error.

I tried `new BigDecimal(21)` but I get an error.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that, but it would be great if there is any way to do that!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the full-qualified name of the class:

```
new java.math.BigDecimal()
```

Answer (score 1):

- make sure the variable "bd" is **not marked final**
- go to the Variables tab, right click on "bd"
- "Change Value..."
- type new java.math.BigDecimal(21), "OK"

Comment: I tried this before posting this question, I get error. "BigDecimal cannot be resolved to a Type".

Answer (score 1):

If you run into any restriction of the debugging views during debugging, then just write a line of code in your already opened Java editor, like

```
bd = new BigDecimal(42);
```

Select that newly written code and from the context menu, choose "[Execute](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/menus/run/ref-menu-run.htm)". Afterwards hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to remove that code and continue debugging. Do not save the editor at any time!

That way you can execute arbitrary fixes during the debugging session.

Comment: "BigDecimal cannot be resolved to a Type". This is the error message I am getting.

Comment: Then your original code does not contain any BigDecimal variable or you are trying to debug some code which does not even compile and run. Fix the errors in your project, before you try to run it.

Comment: I tried doing this in change variable window, so I got the error. Yes, if I write a line of code and select that line and right click - execute will set the new value to the variable of type BigDecimal. continue the debugging. If you are in a loop then you need to execute the line of code every time, other wise the value will not be set. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I was having some problems too for modify the value of a BigDecimal variable while debugging, but I discovered a little trick that maybe could help you: copy in the Java class you're debugging some code for modify the variable, for example `myVar = myVar.add(new BigDecimal(1))` (in this example, `myVar` is a BigDecimal variable and I'm adding it 1) and evaluate that expression (Ctrl + Shift + i), it would assign the new value. Of course, you should save the original value and assign it again before continue the execution, this is just a workaround.
 Hope it helps, regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Change Object Value" dialog of Eclipse enter

```
java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(20)
```

You cannot create a BigInteger with the BigInteger(YOUR_INT) because this constructor is not public. 
Go to the Variables view in Eclipse and Open the "Change Object Value" (right click on the variable of type BigInteger you want to change). 
[Change Object Value Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JedIp.png)